# Rails option_select helper label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Using a bootstrap and rails along with datatables but keep getting a blank option on the datatable instead of a List helper that displays a topic label in the options list.

```
<%= f.label :activity, 'Select Activity' %><br />
            <%= f.select :activity, options_for_select([
            ['#', 'Subject'],
            ['Math', 'Math'],
            ['Science', 'Science'],
            ['English', 'English']
            ]) %>
```

Here's how it looks on the filter page listing all postings should have the subject field displayed instead of blank space:
[image]

Thanks for your help,
RS

Comment: post your code.

Comment: oops formatting issue, posted it above

Answer (score 0):

Rails's `select` [accepts an argument](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) for the empty value, so you can change your code to be the following (Since I don't think you want the Subject to be selectable):

```
<%= f.label :activity, 'Select Activity' %><br />
<%= f.select :activity, options_for_select([
        ['Math', 'Math'],
        ['Science', 'Science'],
        ['English', 'English']
        ]), include_blank: "Subject" %>
```

You can also improve your code by doing the following:

```
<%= f.label :activity, 'Select Activity' %><br />
<% activities = %w(Math Science English) %>
<%= f.select :activity, options_for_select(activities.zip(activities)), include_blank: "Subject") %>
```

Comment: I think my problem may be in jQuery for Datatables but unfortunately this didn't work.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670464/jquery-datatables-individual-column-searching-labels-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

[option_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) give you as option to select a value, you can select a value either from collection or can give your own.

In your case

```
<%= f.label :activity, 'Select Activity' %><br />
            <%= f.select :activity, options_for_select([
            ['#', 'Subject'],
            ['Math', 'Math'],
            ['Science', 'Science'],
            ['English', 'English']
            ] , selected: "Math" ) %>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: got around to trying it, unfortunately it didn't.  It added an extra menu option to it.  I think it may be in the jQuery itself of data tables.

Comment: @rSV No you can fix it using helper itself ..... See [http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select](options_for_select) used to accept two parameter.

Comment: It to works for my `f.select` for `option_select` in the form with  `:include_blank => false`, but it's just not working with the actual posting for jQuery data tables.  The jQuery tables are also showing the values not the labels.  So I think it's something to do with jQuery datatables, not my ruby.